# Who pays for gas fee of POAP?

Tags: nft, gnosis, gnosis-chain

I know we can mint POAP NFT for free. One question I have is who is paying for the gas?

Looking at the POAP transaction it looks like NOT FREE GAS FEE, and someone else mint my POAP NFT. Who is`0xc33557d52ed424a5b7014f06e4d98c4bfc71ef59`  ?

https://blockscout.com/xdai/mainnet/tx/0xcfc093f016b02fff2e4cdb049774e609fd207f399385143cc06ae16a8fceaf33

I tried to mint an NFT at Gnosis(XDAI) and it was not minted for free. Who pays for POAP's gas fee?

Comment: Have you tried ask this in POAP community chat?

Comment: No, not yet. I will try it thanks.

Comment: I tried ask this in [POAP community](https://discord.com/channels/622859637309571072/623151025276059648/1005120891493027940). Because POAP cover all of the costs of minting these NFTs, we can mint POAP NFT for free.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried ask this in [POAP community](https://discord.com/channels/622859637309571072/623151025276059648/1005120891493027940). Because POAP cover all of the costs of minting these NFTs, we can mint POAP NFT for free.